# Identifying Name/Purpose of piece of ellipsoid glassware with internal tube?

Tags: equipment

I recently went to a market in Southern France and found this little piece of equipment for sale along with a whole bunch of other chemistry things. the guy had no idea what it was for or where he'd gotten it from, but for €1 I decided I had to have it because I've never seen anything quite like it (and I'm mildly infatuated with old chemistry equipment...). I'm wondering if anyone here would be able to identify it?

An image with a 10 pence coin for size comparison.
[image: glassware_image]

My first thought was some sort of condenser, because the design is a quite similar due to the external jacket with an internal tube. However on closer inspection the internal tube has a cut out section which would mean any coolant would mix with the substance being condensed.

this diagram shows a little bit more detail about the internal construction of the piece (cross-section):

[image: Glassware-diagram]

There is also some text on the body of the tube which says:

> EX 2ml COLD E - MIL LINE

Thanks for any information someone could give me about what this piece of equipment is and/or what it was used for.

Comment: Could it be a liquid/vapor separator? If you invert the drawing, liquid entering either of the bottom tubes would exit the other, but vapor could exit the large-diameter tube. The side-exit of the inner tube could direct liquid spray away from the vapor tube.

Comment: It could be a kind of "atomizer" giving a sprayed flow out of the little "outlet"?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/chemistry/comments/rqiaij/is_anyone_able_to_identify_this_glassware/ - related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you got there is a **tilting head dispenser/tilting pipette dispenser**. You are lucky that you found one for €1 because it usually costs around $20.

It is small in size because it is to be fitted on the mouth of a container and so called by another name "bottle-top dispenser".

Its is to be attached to a bottle or reservoir, its main function is to dispense the liquid from the container in precise volumes. It is usually used in the fields of analytical chemistry, molecular biology, and pharmaceutical research where accuracy and precision of volumes matter.

[image]

> Flask tilts back to fill to desired volume, forward to dispense.

Source: https://www.coleparmer.com/p/kimax-tilting-dispenser/43264